# Is it safe to create a tarball of a Time Machine backup?

Tags: backup, time-machine, tar

Is it possible for me to create a `.tar.gz`, `.tar.xz`, etc file of a `.backupdb`? Are there any precautions I need to take to ensure that all permissions, hardlinks, etc are preserved? Will `tar` destroy the de-duplication used in Time Machine's backups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tar does not preserve all the information in the HFS filesystem.

I would look at having it converted to a image file instead.  I believe Disk Utility can do this for a folder.